# Completely fresh 16.04 install, still seeing Antergos in boot menu

Tags: boot

I want a completely clean Ubuntu 16.04LTS install, I previously had Antergos on this machine.

I have tried selecting the erase everything option, I have tried removing partitions and readding them on install but either way if I hit F12 on boot I get these options:

ubuntu

antergos_grub

HDD

USB

How can I remove Antergos completely?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to see if you can find the entry for it in there. If it is try erasing that partition again (if this is what you want) but using a live disc with gparted.

Comment: I've done a search in that file, no mention of Antergos at all

Comment: Did you try searching the same directory in other partitions?

Comment: Ive managed to remove it using this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/63613/300427

Comment: Sorry, did my best ✌️